# Is this a valid sentence: "[This] is [that] made [аdjective]"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

For example, can I say "Ambalco is cycling videos made interactive"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as my interpretation is correct:

These videos, which have already been made interactive are now being cycled (I'm guessing this means "looped" or distributed in a rotation) by Ambalco.

I'm assuming Ambalco is not the one who made the videos interactive. If Ambalco is the one who did and this needs to be known, it would be correct to phrase it like this:

"Ambalco is cycling videos it (he, she, they) made interactive."

I'm also assuming Ambalco is a company.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you answer and totally accept it. It's clear for me that I should use less ambigous phrase: "Ambalco is about making indoor cycling videos interactive" or something of that kind

Comment: Oh! You meant "indoor cycling"! Now I get it. lol

Comment: So, cycling is a noun here. I interpreted it as a verb. "Ambalco is distributing videos it made interactive." I think you're right to be less ambiguous by adding the "indoor" to it.